# Exim Can Send Email but Not Receive

Tags: centos, centos7, exim

After reinstalling exim on CentOS 7 I can send emails, but I do not receive them, (not even replies to emails I've sent).

The client sending me an email does not get any error bounce-back - from their point of view the email was sent without problem.

I've checked in my spam for these emails, and I have the same issue with two accounts on the same VPS.

It's worth noting that reinstalling exim was a bit of a fiddle, mostly to do with the having to get the config file from another source, so I have a feeling the problem lies therein.

I've looked for the missing emails in:

/home/admin/mail/

/etc/mail/

but I can't find them in there. Is there somewhere else I should look for the emails?

I've also setup a forwarding rule for all incoming messages to see if they get that far and are sent on. They're not.

Looking through the exim.conf file hasn't shown anything obvious (although I'm not very familiar with it):

Here's the Access Control section for incoming SMTP from exim.conf ([here's the whole file](http://pastebin.com/asyua6Df)):

```
begin acl

acl_check_spammers:
  accept  hosts         = +whitelist

  drop    message       = Your host in blacklist on this server.
          log_message   = Host in blacklist
          hosts         = +spammers

  accept


acl_check_mail:
  deny    condition     = ${if eq{$sender_helo_name}{}}
          message       = HELO required before MAIL

  drop    message       = Helo name contains a ip address (HELO was $sender_helo_name) and not is valid
          condition     = ${if match{$sender_helo_name}{\N((\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3})|([0-9a-f]{8})|([0-9A-F]{8}))\N}{yes}{no}}
          condition     = ${if match {${lookup dnsdb{>: defer_never,ptr=$sender_host_address}}\}{$sender_helo_name}{no}{yes}}
          delay         = 45s

  drop    condition     = ${if isip{$sender_helo_name}}
          message       = Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)

  drop    condition     = ${if eq{[$interface_address]}{$sender_helo_name}}
          message       = $interface_address is _my_ address

  accept


acl_check_rcpt:
  accept  hosts         = :

  deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
          domains       = +local_domains
          local_parts   = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|]

  deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
          domains       = !+local_domains
          local_parts   = ^[./|] : ^.*[@%!] : ^.*/\\.\\./

  require verify        = sender

  accept  hosts         = +relay_from_hosts
          control       = submission

  accept  authenticated = *
          control       = submission/domain=

  deny    message       = Rejected because $sender_host_address is in a black list at $dnslist_domain\n$dnslist_text
          hosts         = !+whitelist
          dnslists      = ${readfile {/etc/exim/dnsbl.conf}{:}}

  require message       = relay not permitted
          domains       = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains

  deny    message       = smtp auth requried
         sender_domains = +local_domains
         !authenticated = *

  require verify        = recipient

.ifdef CLAMD
  warn    set acl_m0    = no

  warn    condition     = ${if exists {/etc/exim/domains/$domain/antivirus}{yes}{no}}
          set acl_m0    = yes
.endif

.ifdef SPAMASSASSIN
  warn    set acl_m1    = no

  warn    condition     = ${if exists {/etc/exim/domains/$domain/antispam}{yes}{no}}
          set acl_m1    = yes
.endif

  accept


acl_check_data:
.ifdef CLAMD
  deny   message        = Message contains a virus ($malware_name) and has been rejected
         malware        = *
         condition      = ${if eq{$acl_m0}{yes}{yes}{no}}
.endif

.ifdef SPAMASSASSIN
  warn   !authenticated = *
         hosts          = !+relay_from_hosts
         condition      = ${if < {$message_size}{100K}}
         condition      = ${if eq{$acl_m1}{yes}{yes}{no}}
         spam           = spamd:true/defer_ok
         add_header     = X-Spam-Score: $spam_score_int
         add_header     = X-Spam-Bar: $spam_bar
         add_header     = X-Spam-Report: $spam_report
         set acl_m2     = $spam_score_int

  warn   condition      = ${if !eq{$acl_m2}{} {yes}{no}}
         condition      = ${if >{$acl_m2}{SPAM_SCORE} {yes}{no}}
         add_header     = X-Spam-Status: Yes
         message        = SpamAssassin detected spam (from $sender_address to $recipients).
.endif

  accept


acl_check_mime:
  deny   message        = Blacklisted file extension detected
         condition      = ${if match {${lc:$mime_filename}}{\N(\.ade|\.adp|\.bat|\.chm|\.cmd|\.com|\.cpl|\.exe|\.hta|\.ins|\.isp|\.jse|\.lib|\.lnk|\.mde|\.msc|\.msp|\.mst|\.pif|\.scr|\.sct|\.shb|\.sys|\.vb|\.vbe|\.vbs|\.vxd|\.wsc|\.wsf|\.wsh)$\N}{1}{0}}

  accept
```

I'm pretty clueless for what to do considering there are no rejection errors I can look at. Does anyone have a suggestions of how I can debug this?

Thank you!

Comment: I am curious if this will tell you anything http://mxtoolbox.com/deliverability Let me know please

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion!! Here's the report: http://mxtoolbox.com/deliverability/74f5596c-16d7-4893-aa8c-40ce21865358 All the SPF stuff is green, but then half way down the page under "Blacklist" there's a green tick for one of the hops, and a red cross for the other. Does the green tick mean it was blacklisted by my server? Anyway, if you can make more sense of it, I'd be really happy to hear what you think!

Comment: I think this is why "SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch Reverse DNS does not contain the hostname" "SMTP Banner Check Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner" makes your spf invalid

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that. Before I uninstalled and reinstalled exim I could send and receive emails with no problem, and I've never had a RDNS entry on my domain. It's on my list of things to do anyway, so I'll try it out. But wouldn't a RDNS mismatch be more likely to stop me from sending emails rather than receive them?

Comment: ahh damnit, you are right, its been a day.